# CKFinder - Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL

Tags: php, fatal-error, ckfinder

I've installed CKFinder and configured it according to the documentation. Unfortunately, when I try to run it by the CKEditor the following statement appears:

> Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL...

What's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you are running a version of PHP lower than 7.1 and the version of CKFinder you are running expects PHP >= 7.1

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm running 7.0 version of PHP, so I have to try higher one.